# Pushing object in stack in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I using stackview in qml.There are two ways to push the componenet into Stackview.
1)By making object of the qml file.
2)By directly giving url under Qt.Resolved for the qml file.
Can someone help me what is difference in both the cases.

What is change in result if everytime we pass pass object will it make new object or it will use the previous one

Comment: [This](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html#item-ownership) part of the docs seems relevant. StackView will only delete Items that it creates from Components or URLs. It will not delete Items that were already created.